# How to write SPI DMA code inside a Rust struct implementation?

Tags: rust, embedded, stm32, spi, dma

I am trying to write a Rust device driver using STM32 SPI DMA. SPI DMA code is quite easy if you look at the [stm32f1xx-hal example](https://github.com/stm32-rs/stm32f1xx-hal/blob/master/examples/spi-dma.rs), but the traits are very complex. I cannot figure out how to get the compiler to accept the following code which fails on the `wait` call.

```rust
impl<SPI, REMAP, PINS, CH> DeviceDriver<SpiTxDma<SPI, REMAP, PINS, CH>>
where SpiTxDma<SPI, REMAP, PINS, CH>: WriteDma<&'static mut [u8], u8>,
{
    pub fn send(&mut self) {
        if let (Some(spi), Some(buf)) = (self.spi.take(), self.buf.take()) {
            let transfer = spi.write(buf);
            let (buf, spi) = transfer.wait();
            self.buf = Some(buf);
            self.spi = Some(spi);
        }
    }
}
```

The error:

```
25 |             let (buf, spi) = txdma.wait();
   |                                    ^^^^ method not found in `Transfer<stm32f1xx_hal::dma::R, &mut [u8], TxDma<SpiPayload<SPI, REMAP, PINS>, CH>>`
```

**However**, if I replace the `CH` type parameter with a fixed struct name [`C5`](https://docs.rs/stm32f1xx-hal/0.7.0/stm32f1xx_hal/dma/dma1/struct.C5.html), it compiles fine.

Why would fixing a type parameter, changing nothing else, cause the code to compile/fail?

Obviously, the above won't work in a playground, so here's the [(non)buildable repo](https://github.com/pozix604/spi_dma).

Answer (score 1):

The `wait` method is only defined if `TxDma<SpiPayload<SPI, REMAP, PINS>, CH>` implements [`TransferPayload`](https://docs.rs/stm32f1xx-hal/0.7.0/stm32f1xx_hal/dma/trait.TransferPayload.html), which is the case for the concrete type `C5` but not for the unconstrained type parameter `CH`. Try adding a constraint to your code:

```
impl<SPI, REMAP, PINS, CH> DeviceDriver<SpiTxDma<SPI, REMAP, PINS, CH>>
where SpiTxDma<SPI, REMAP, PINS, CH>: WriteDma<&'static mut [u8], u8>,
      TxDma<SpiPayload<SPI, REMAP, PINS>, CH>: TransferPayload,
{
    pub fn send(&mut self) {
        if let (Some(spi), Some(buf)) = (self.spi.take(), self.buf.take()) {
            let transfer = spi.write(buf);
            let (buf, spi) = transfer.wait();
            self.buf = Some(buf);
            self.spi = Some(spi);
        }
    }
}
```